# How to check if an attribute value has been set during the process flow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to know if there is a way to check if an attribute value has been *set* during the process flow. That is, I have an `Article` class with attributes `title`, `content`, `updater_user_id`.

In my controller I have:

```
# @article.title
# => "Sample title"
# @article.content
# => "Sample content"
# @article.updater_user_id
# => 1

# @current_user.id
# => 1 # Note: This value is the same as '@article.updater_user_id'
@article.updater_user_id = @current_user.id

# params[:article]
# => {:article => {:title => 'Sample title 2', :content => 'Sample content 2'}}
@article.update_attributes(params[:article])
```

I tried to use the [`@article.changed`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty/changed) method but it doesn't work as I would like it to work. In fact, that method returns:

```
@article.changed
# => ['title', 'content'] # Note: There isn't the 'updater_user_id' attribute
```

*In other words, I would like to check if the `updater_user_id` has been set during the process flow even if that value has not changed.* My use case is that I would like to *require* that the `updater_user_id` is set (at least one time) during the process flow before to save an `Article` object; if it is not set during the process flow, then I would like to raise an error or something like that.

**Is it possible? If so, how to make that?**

Comment: Wait, so you want to check if it has been set, even when the value of the attribute didn't change? What's the use case of this?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - I would like to require that the `updater_user_id` is set each time an Article object is saved otherwise I would like to raise an error or something like that.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not a big fan of code that enforces something like that, but that's just me. Also, AFAIK there's no built-in Rails construct to do this. You could probably achieve it by overriding `updater_user_id=` and maybe adding an `after_save`. There are lots of different ways to set things though and it'd be difficult to enforce it universally.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - Can you provide an example code that I can use to achieve what you are saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `xxx_will_change!` method?

```
# in Article class
  def updater_user_id=(new_updater_user_id)
    self[:updater_user_id] = new_updater_user_id
    updater_user_id_will_change!
  end
```

Comment: It doesn't work as expected (maybe it is because the `@article.changed` method doesn't "include" the `updater_user_id` attribute).

Comment: I've tested the code on my model. It worked fine! The code `product.id = product.id; product.changed` returned `["id"]`. Maybe you've made a typo?

Comment: Have you used code as-like made in code stated in the question body? For example, have you stated code in the controller file and all variable statuses/values are the same as I stated? That is, the "context" is the same? Given my "context", the `@article.changed` returns `['title', 'content']` and not `['title', 'content', 'updater_user_id']` (maybe it happens because the `@article.updater_user_id` value is equal to the `@current_user.id` value and so Ruby on Rails fills that is has not changed).

Comment: I showed you an example: `product.id = product.id` (left side is the same as right side). By default this won't cause the `id` to be mentioned among changed attributes, but with `updater_user_id_will_change!` it should appear there. NOTE: this call is made AFTER the actual assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, and there may be some unforeseen caveats, but you could likely do something like:

```
def updater_user_id=(val)
  @updater_user_id_set = true
  write_attribute :updater_user_id, val
end

def updater_user_id_set?
  @updater_user_id_set || updater_user_id_changed?
end

def clear_updater_user_id_set
  @updater_user_id_set = false
end
private :clear_updater_user_id_set

after_save :clear_updater_user_id_set
```

This overrides `updater_user_id=` to save a flag that the field has been updated, then has a method to check that it is set (presumably you'd want to use this in a validation or something?). Finally a hook is added to clear the flag when the object is saved.